# Where should power factor correction and active harmonic filter connected?

Tags: transformer, power-factor-correction, harmonics

After mains electricity meter, there is an isolation transformer (delta to star) and all load is connected to the secondary of the isolation transformer.

We plan to install a power factor correction device and an active harmonic filter. Our load is unbalanced (lots of single phase split AC that gets turned on and off as per use) and active harmonic filter should be able to balance the load as well.

Our concern is that if connected to the primary, it might not be able to balance the load (since neutral is not even connected to isolation transformer's primary side) and if we connect this to secondary it won't be able to correct power factor as necessary since it won't be able to compensate isolation transformer losses

Should we connect it to the primary of isolation transformer or at secondary of the transformer?

**Update 1**
[image]

Comment: The transformation ratio of the transformer is 1, right? Also, why are you connecting the filter after the meter, not before it?

Comment: Main power meter is on the primary -- so is that the utility's side? If so, you may not be allowed to install anything else on the primary.

Comment: @Hazem Yes, the transformer is 1:1 ratio. Mains meter is installed by the power distribution company and we can alter or change anything before meter.

Comment: @C.Lange Yes primary is at utility side but the isolation transformer would be installed by us for safety reasons and we can connect anything after the meter.